# Pass Environment Variable as command line argument

Tags: variables, cmd, environment, hostname

I am trying to script the install of an application that requires the hostname be in the argument string.

"C:\application.exe" /host=hostname

But it keeps taking whatever I put as the argument value as a literal.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `%hostname%` is how you use environment variables in windows.

Comment: Maybe `"C:\application.exe" /host=%COMPUTERNAME%`?

Answer (score 3):

%hostname% is how you use environment variables in windows.

```
c:\application.exe /host=%hostname%
```

Comment: When I do that it treats it as plain text.  The applications takes the value and adds it to a configuration file.  So the config file now contains hostname =%hostname%